# Why does Laravel array cast sort the elements, and can it be avoided?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a JSON field in a database which is populated using the array cast on an Eloquent model.

Before saving the field, Laravel sorts the elements by their key.  Presumably this happens during serialisation.

Why does it do this?  And is there a way to prevent it?

Comment: Take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20912492/4848587

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need to implement search by field, you can use the **text** type instead of the **json** type. Just before saving, you will need to execute **json_encode**, either yourself or implement a mutator.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes MySQL changes the order of keys when a JSON field is used.

The basic solution is to use a TEXT field to store json.

See [Mysql 5.7 native json support - control keys order in json_insert function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38910924/mysql-5-7-native-json-support-control-keys-order-in-json-insert-function)

Answer (score 0):

I've never encountered this behavior before, but perhaps you can try using an accessor and a mutator to accomplish what you want. Let's say your database column is `meta`. You can use Laravel's special `setAttribute` and `getAttribute` methods in your model.

**[A mutator](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator)**

For example, to `json_encode` data as it's about to be saved to your database it would be:

```
public function setMetaAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['meta'] = json_encode($value);
}
```

**[An accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor)**

To `json_decode` data as it's being retrieved it would be:

```
public function getMetaAttribute($value)
{
    return json_decode($value, true);
}
```

The rule of thumb is take `get` or `set` and append your column name with first letters uppercased and removing any underscores, and appending `Attribute` to the method name. E.g. `active_users` column becomes `getActiveUsersAttribute` and so on.

Try that and see if it does any funky sorting.